# How can i sum up the last row value of a column in each group in a rdlc report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

I want to add only the last row value of any column of each group in a rdlc report, so,
iam having an rdlc group report, which has a balance column, so what i want is to add the last balance value of each group in the report,here is how my table looks like '

```
Customer   Balance
  Mark       1500
  Mark       2500
-----------------------
  Steve     4500
  Steve     5600
-----------------------
 Alex      10000
 Alex      24000
```

' .and i want to add the last balance value of each Customer, which is 2500+5600+24000, here is the rdlc expression i have tried before and which did not work:

```
'=SUM(LAST(fields!balance.value),"mygroup")'
```

I would be glad if someone provides me the solution of fixing this problem.

Comment: Is "mygroup" the name of the rowgroup that groups by customer?

Comment: mygroup is the group name, which has grouped the data by any other column say product name, customer is just a column within the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have realised, you can't use FIRST, LAST etc in an outer aggregate but there is away to get around it.

First I replicated your data, but I also added a sort column. I assume you will have a column to sort on already (an invoice number of date etc).

The trick is to sum only if the sort value is the same as the maximum sort value for the group, it will be clearer with an example.

Here's the  sample data I produced.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Customer varchar(50), sort int, Amount int)
  INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('Mark', 1, 1500),
    ('Mark', 2, 2500),
    ('Steve', 1, 4500),
    ('Steve', 2, 5600),
    ('Alex', 1, 10000),
    ('Alex', 2, 24000)

  SELECT * FROM @t
```

Next I created a new report, added the above query as a dataset query and added simple table to the report.

I added a Row Group to group by `Customer` and sorted that group by `sort`.

I then added a final row outside the groups and set the expression to give the results you require.

Here's the simple report layout.

[image]

Here's the expression I used.

```
=Sum(
    IIF(
        Fields!sort.Value = MAX(Fields!sort.Value, "Customer"),
        Fields!Amount.Value,
        0
        )
    )
```

**Note:** The `"Customer"` string refers to the Row Group name (highlighted in the image), not the dataset column.

Here is the final output

[image]

Comment: Ok..so you mean to say that sort is a key column of that table and the rdlc expression is looking for the max value of that key within the group and takes its corresponding balance value from each group..it seems like a good solution even though i am not showing my key column in the report but i can take it into the dataset and perform the same expression...Thanks a lot Alan..

Comment: Its does not have to be a key column, just something that you sort on in order to know which is the last value. Other than that, yes, you are correct. If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the vote up/down buttons)

Comment: It worked for me.. and exactly how i wanted it to...your hint was good enough to work for me....cheers..